# Can't cure vampirism: Falion won't interact

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I am tired of being a vampire, so I'm trying to complete the *Rising at Dawn* quest. I've spoken to Falion initially, given him a filled black soul gem, and met him at dawn in the black swamp, but I can't *Speak to Falion*, which is the trigger for the ritual to actually cure me. He just stands there. (I've recently drunk blood – this is not about people attacking me.)

I can talk to him about other things, why he's in Morthal, etc, but I can't trigger the ritual.

[Steam forum suggests this is a glitch](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2235232) and even has a fix, but that fix requires you to type a code in the console. I don't know how to do that in the PS3, if it's even possible.

I'm having a lot of trouble with the 75% fire weakness. How can I stop being a vampire?

Comment: for pc users you can go to my documents>games>skyrim or something and then delete the skyrim and skyrimprefs file and start the game, you just have to adjust your settings again

Comment: This question is really specific to consoles that don't support entering cheat codes, etc. The `ps3` tag should indicate that, but it was removed by an editor. I just added it back.

Comment: I had this problem myself on PS3, it was solved by waiting in 1 hour chunks until Fallion decided to talk to me.  I also believe he decided to talk to me at the wrong time of day in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have not yet completed the Companions quests you can go and do the storyline. Around the middle you get lyncanthropy (turn into a werewolf) and vampirism will be replaced with a kick ass power to turn into a werewolf

Comment: This sounds like a good idea; assuming there are no more glitches, if I cure lycanthropy later on will I still be a vamp?

Comment: I've become a werewolf and the vampirisim effects are gone. I'll mark this as the answer. (I reserve the right to unmark it, though, if getting rid of lycanthropy simply reverts me to being a vamp.) :)

Answer (score 1):

go with fast travel to any place , then come again with fast travel to Morthal. Then go to the down and you can talk to Falion.